# Deploy using JBoss and Intellij

Tags: java, spring, rest, intellij-idea, jboss

Currently I am deploying my Java Spring code using JBoss server. What I am doing each time I do a change to code is

1. build the project using mvn clean install
2. Copy created war file to \wildfly-10.1.0\standalone\deployments
3. Deploy using $ ./standalone.sh --debug 8787

This works fine but the procedure is too long. Is there a method easier than this using Intellij IDE or another method.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry i have no idea with **Intellij** and **JBoss**,

but with **Maven** project you should try **JBoss Devstudio** [Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio](https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/)

> it's free and is **Eclipse** extended

you will can run instantly and debug your java code directly.